# Statically distinguish between an enum and an enum class in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, enumeration, static-assert, enum-class

I have an event handler class that uses a template argument to set the event type. I want to enforce these event types to be **enum classes** of one byte size. Static assertion against the size is not an issue, but I cannot find information online on how to statically distinguish between an *enum* and *enum class*.

The solution I have now is to assert for enums using the [C++ front-end implements syntactic extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Type-Traits.html) and then assert the correct size. On most platforms this works, since an enum uses the `int` type (which most often is larger than one byte).

But this would lead to slightly misleading error messages. I like to be thorough.

**What checks could I do that would pass on a class enum, but fail with a regular old enum?**

---

**I cannot use `type_traits`**, since the compiler I use (*avr-gcc*) does not support it. I am however continuously implementing my own `type_traits`, when a need rises. So any tips on solutions in `type_traits` could still be useful!

---

**Minimal example:**

```
// Event types
enum class tPass     : uint8_t  {}; 
enum class tFailSize : uint16_t {}; // Fail on size!
enum       tFailType            {}; // Currently fails on size, would like to fail on type!

// Event handler
template <typename TEvent>
class tEventHandler 
{
    static_assert(__is_enum(TEvent),   "Must be class enum!"); // Doesn't really check for CLASS enums
    static_assert(1 == sizeof(TEvent), "Must be one byte!");
};
```

**Usage:**

```
auto handler = tEventHandler<tPass>();   // Ok!
// auto handler2 = tEventHandler<tFailSize>(); // error: static assertion failed: Must be one byte!
// auto handler3 = tEventHandler<tFailType>(); // error: static assertion failed: Must be one byte! <----- THIS
```

**Goal:**

```
auto handler = tEventHandler<tPass>();   // Ok!
// auto handler2 = tEventHandler<tFailSize>(); // error: static assertion failed: Must be one byte!
// auto handler3 = tEventHandler<tFailType>(); // error: static assertion failed: Must be class enum! <--- THIS
```

Answer (score 6):

A key distinction between unscoped enumerations and the scoped kind (`enum class`), is that the former implicitly convert to their underlying type, whereas the latter do not. Since you are interested in how the `type_traits` solution would look, you can check (not entirely tested, may not be SFINAE friendly):

```
static_assert(std::is_enum<TEvent>::value, "Must be a scoped enum!"); 
static_assert(!std::is_convertible<TEvent, typename std::underlying_type<TEvent>::type>::value,
              "Must be a scoped enum!");
```

If AVR-GCC has an `underlying_type` intrinsic, then you need only supplement the `is_convertible` trait (which is even implementable in C++03).